# How do linq expressions work with dynamic objects in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I currently use linq expressions to create some dynamic objects using the new features of .net 4.0 such as the DLR.

So from my understanding the compiler can generate these sort of expressions. I also saw that the DynamicMetaObjects used by the framework actually has an underlying linq expression.

But from my point of view these expressions really seem static and I hardly understand how are they evaluated. Are they compiled or just include instructions in them so simulate normal code?

Also how do they fit with the rest of the DLR stuff?

Comment: Just take a look at some of the generated expressions in the debugger.  That's probably the simplest way to see how they are represented.

Comment: @Servy If it`s contains lambda he can't see it debuggin!

Comment: @Fals Sure you can...why couldn't you?